# Optimizing code solution for Palindrome Index-Hackerrank

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I submitted my solution for palindrome Index coding challenge but I get "test cases terminated due to time out error". My code is working and so I don't know what else to do to optimize it. Please help:

```
function palindromeIndex(s) {
    let palindrome = s === s.split('').reverse().join('')
    if(!palindrome) {
        let i = 0
        let integerIndex = []
        let arr = s.split('')
        while(i < s.length) {
            arr.splice(i,1)
            if(arr.join('') === arr.reverse().join('')) {
               integerIndex.push(i) 
            }
            arr = s.split('')
            i++
        }
        return integerIndex.length > 0 ? integerIndex[0] : - 1
    }else {
        return -1
    }
}
```

Comment: Challenge sites require you to figure out a trick that doesn't require looping through all the possibilities. This is not ordinary programming, you need to be extra clever.

Comment: You need to explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: checking by character will terminate early for cases, doesn't use as much memory, and will be faster.  also caching

Comment: @Barmar, Could you please use an example to explain? I have tried but it is not working still.

Comment: @user120242, Could you please use an example to explain this?

Comment: I have no idea what the solution is, that's why I don't waste my time on challenge sites like this.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem.
so I tried this and passed.

```
function reverseString(slicedStr){
        return slicedStr.split('').reverse().join('');
}
    
function palindromeIndex(s) {
    if(s === reverseString(s)) return -1;
    
    const sLeng = s.length
    for(let i=0; i<sLeng/2; i++){
        if(s[i]===s[sLeng-i-1]) continue; // this part makes it better.
        
        const slicedStr = s.substr(0,i) + s.substr(i + 1);
        if(slicedStr === reverseString(slicedStr)) return i;
        else return sLeng - i - 1;
    }
}
```

It was like below when I can't pass.

```
function palindromeIndex(s) {
    if(s === reverseString(s)) return -1;
    
    for(let i=0; i<s.length; i++){
        const slicedStr = s.substr(0,i) + s.substr(i + 1);
        if(slicedStr === reverseString(slicedStr)) return i;
    }
}
```

hope someone get help :)